# New line '\n' not recognized inside TextField in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, textfield

#### Context

I am using Material UI TextField and mapping an array of objects which is fetched from Database (MongoDB). Something like:

```js
{state.map((item) => (
         <TextField
          name="description"
          multiline
          required
          type="text"
          value={item.description}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />)
      )
}
```

Where `state` is the array fetched from the database.

#### Problem

The `item.description` is displayed as it is with `\n` escape sequences instead of separating the line into new lines.

#### Examples

[image: How the input component looks like]

[image: How the output is rendered]

#### Additional Info

- When I try to do `console.log(item.description.split('\n'))` inside my React code I get the following output in the console -

[image: Console.log output]

As if JS is not even recognizing `\n` !! BUT in the same place when I run it the console I get this -

[image: Console.log running the same command]

**Thanks in advance!**
Please let me know if anything else is needed to understand the problem better

Comment: `\n` is not recognized by html input as next line , so you can replace this before providing this value to your input by the asci char `&#10;`   `item.description.replace("\n","&#10;")`

Comment: I tried to replace `\n` with ` &#10;` in the MongoDB Cloud document (since data is being received from there) and this is what I got in the Description TextField -  `* This is line one &#10; * This is line two \n*` .  Although the  `&#10;` doesn't show in the preview, it does not change the line in the preview too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently I solved this by creating a helper function using replace and regex global search

```js
const parseLines = (value) => value.replace(/(\\n)/g, "\n");
```

I realized I had to use `\\n` instead of `\n` to detect the string pattern of `\n` and replace it with newline which is simply `\n`.

And later in in TextField

```js
<TextField               
 name="description"              
 multiline
 required
 type="text"
 value={parseLines(item.description)}
 onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Comment: I had a similar issue when using TextAreaAutosize after saving a 'description' with multiple paragraphs to GCP Firestore and then pulling that data into the application on update forms. I resolved the issue by using replaceAll.

`const parseLines = (value) => value.replaceAll(/(\\n)/g, "\n");`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `<p>` to display ur descriptions. It automatically makes a new line for each element. If that doesn't work use the `<br>` tag after every line. You can use it to add a line break manually.

Comment: When I try to replace the "\n" with the `<br/>` tag the bug remains, just that now in the text area it literally shows `<br/>` instead of `\n` :(